# How can I build a Wix project on a remote build server?

Tags: wpf, continuous-integration, wix, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have a Wix installer project for my WPF application, and I am trying to integrate this project into my CI/CD pipeline (Github Actions). Currently, I don't know how to build this project on the build server. The Wix documentation says that I could just check-in the Wix tooling with the actual source code, but this seems like a bad idea. What is the most recommended way of building WiX projects on Github Actions or more generally on a remote build sever?

Comment: GitHub Actions Windows environment already has WiX installed along with VS, like https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md So to build your WiX projects (`*.wixproj`), just use the typical MSBuild command (`msbuild A.wixproj`).

Comment: That worked!! If you want to make this an actual answer to my SO question, I'll add mark it as the answer. Thank much. I spent a long time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub Actions Windows environment already has WiX installed along with VS.

So to build your WiX projects (`*.wixproj`), just use the typical MSBuild command `msbuild A.wixproj`.